# Create folders from txt file and if folders haven't been created write name ino error file

Tags: bash

I have been trying to create script which reads txt file(source.txt) and creating folders with this name and if folder somehow haven't been created I need to put name in Error.txt

Here I have script for windows which is **working**, but I need to create it for linux

Windows:

```
for /F "usebackq eol=| delims=" %G in ("source.txt") do md "Fld1\%~G" 2>nul & if not exist "Fld1\%~G">>"Error.txt"
```

Linux script throws error "syntax error near unexpected token done, without `if [ ! -d Fld1/$line ] then echo "$line" > Error.txt` script works correctly creating all I want, but I need this script with this if case.

```
while read line;
do
mkdir "Fld1/$line"
if [ ! -d Fld1/$line ]
then
echo "$line" > Error.txt
done < source.txt
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mkdir` already tells you if it suceeded.

`fi` is missing.

I think you want to `>>` append to file.

Check your scripts with shellcheck . You script might look like:

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
   if ! mkdir "Fld1/$line"; then
      echo "Fld1/$line" >> Error.txt
   fi
done < source.txt
```

I think I would consider:

```
cd "Fld1" && xargs -d '\n' -n1 mkdir <source.txt 2>Error.txt
```